# Symfony 2 namespace error only in production ("Attempted to load class...)

Tags: php, symfony, namespaces, psr-4

I am working on a **Symfony 2** website, and having an issue **only in production** (cache is clear).

I am using the **Payplug php api** : I' ve put the files in the vendor folder, I use the namespace for the classes I use, and everything is ok on my local dev environment.

Once on the **prod server**, I get the error:

`"Attempted to load class "Payplug" from namespace "Payplug". Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?"`

I don't get why it gets a namespace error only on the prod server...

**CONTROLLER :**

```
<?php

    namespace KpmBundle\Controller;

    use KpmBundle\Entity\Marche;
    use KpmBundle\Entity\Marcheur;
    use KpmBundle\Entity\Commande;
    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    use Payplug\Payplug as Payplug;
    use Payplug\Payment as Payment;

    class MarcheController extends Controller
    {
        //code

        Payplug::setSecretKey(...);

        //more code
    }
```

**CLASS**

```
<?php
    namespace Payplug;

    /**
     * The Payment DAO simplifies the access to most useful methods
     **/
    class Payment
    {
```

I really wonder why everything works fine on my local dev server ( app_dev.php and app.php ), but goes wrong on prod server...

Any idea would be appreciated,

regards

**EDIT**
*The files where installed via composer*

Comment: I suppose you could try a "composer dumpautoload" on your production server but, from what you described, it probably won't help.

Comment: unhapily I have no ssh access, only ftp transfer... what file could be modified ?

Comment: When you did the transfer, did you transfer the entire vendor directory or just the payplug stuff?  You need to make sure that all the stuff under vendor/composer is in sync between production and development.

Comment: I pushed the payplug stuff alone, and I see different sizes on the files under vendor/composer... you might have solved my problem !

Comment: @cerad Good job, my vendor/composer wasnt sync with the dev one. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using **FTP**, and transfered the `vendor\payplug` directory alone to the remote server ; as a result the `vendor\composer` wasn't sync between local and remote server.
transfering the local `vendor\composer` solved the problem

Thx to @cerad